# Approximating the Kullback-Leibler Divergence with a Laplace approximation

Tags: normal-distribution, asymptotics, kullback-leibler, laplace-approximation

Suppose I wish to compute the (asymptotic) Kullback-Leibler Divergence (KLD) between the exact Bayesian posterior 
$$q_{n}(\theta|x_{1:n}) \propto \pi(\theta)\prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i|\theta)$$ 
and the prior $\pi$ upon which it is based in closed form, irrespective of the likelihood model $p(x_i|\theta)$ used to arrive at $q_n$. Suppose also that we know that $q_n$ itself satisfies a Bernstein-von-Mises Theorem, i.e. is asymptotically normal with the same distribution as the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE). In other words, I want to have an asymptotically exact approximation to
$$ \mathbb{E}_{q_n}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n\log(p(x_i|\theta))\right]$$
Is it feasible to apply a Laplace transformation for each term, i.e. to approximate the above as 
$$\left[
    \pi(\hat{\theta}_n)e^{\sum_{j=1}^n\log(p(x_j|\hat{\theta}_n)) }
    \left( \dfrac{2\pi}{n} \right)^{d/2}
    |\mathcal{I}(\hat{\theta}_n, x)|^{-1/2}
    \left(\sum_{i=1}^n
    \log(p(x_i|\hat{\theta}_n)) 
    %+ \log(\pi(\hat{\theta}_n))
    \right)
    \right]\cdot \left( 1 + O\left(n^{-1}\right)\right)
    $$
where I have dropped/ignored the normalizing constant of $q_n$, where $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE and $\mathcal{I}(\hat{\theta}_n, x)$ the Fisher information matrix given as usual by
$$\mathcal{I}(\hat{\theta}_n, x) = -\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{\partial^2 \sum_{j=1}^n\log(p(x_j|\theta))}{\partial\theta\partial\theta^T}\Big|_{\theta = \hat{\theta}_n}$$
I cannot find anything wrong with the steps I take here, but if I use this approximation in a proof I arrive at a contradiction. What am I overlooking here? Any help in pointing me to the problem is very much appreciated!